# How do I use tmhOAuth to send an image stored in mysql DB to twitter

Tags: mysql, json, twitter, media

I am using the code below to post a status and an image to twitter. The library is tmhOAuth, the image is coming from a blob in my mysql db as is the mime type and file name.

Basically if an image is found stored in the db row then it sends to twitter using a post to "update_with_media" if no image is found then it just sends the status update alone using "update". the "update" works fine, but I can't get the update with media working. I've tried several variations from various sites including Twitter's dev site but no joy. I'd really appreciate any help with this.

```
if(!empty($imgid)) {

$getimg = mysql_query("SELECT filedata, filename, mime_type FROM post_images WHERE id = $imgid");
$img = @mysql_fetch_array($getimg); 

$imagedata = $img['filedata'];
$imagename = $img['filename'];
$imagetype = $img['mime_type'];                                     

$theimg = "@{$imagedata};type=$imagetype;filename={$imagename}";
$hasimg = "y";                  
}

if($hasimg == "y") {
    $code = $connection->request( 'POST',  
    $connection->url('https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json'),
   array(
        'media[]'  => $theimg,
        'status'   => $thetweet),
    true, // use auth
    true  // multipart
);
} else {
    $code = $connection->request('POST', 
    $connection->url('1.1/statuses/update'), 
    array('status' => $thetweet));
}

// A response code of 200 is a success
if ($code == 200) {
  print "Tweet sent";
} else {
  print "Error: $code";
}
```

Comment: anyone? Really? This is still not working for me - I appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone else has a similar issue my problem was formatting. Instead of using the variable "$theimg", I replaced

```
'media[]'  => $theimg, with 'media[]'  => "$imagedata; type=$imagetype; filename=$imagename"
```

Hope that helps someone...

Peace!